# In Windows 11 my user is admin but OS doesn't allow me to open device manager

Tags: windows-11, bluetooth, administrator, device-manager

After one wrong click I got the upgrade to Windows 11 and now my bluetooth drivers does not work anymore. I'm trying to reinstall them, but although my user is Adminstrator I get the following message when I try to open Device Manager:

> Operation canceled due to existing restrictions on the computer. Contact the System Administrator

This is my translation of the original message in Brazilian Portuguese:

> Operação cancelada devido a restrições existentes no computador. Contate o administrador do sistema.

If I open a console and run

```
netwmic useraccount get name,sid
```

It says that my user is in the Administrator(es) group:

```
Associações de Grupo Local          *Administradores
                                    *Administradores do Hy
                                    *docker-users
                                    *Usuários
                                    *Usuários de log de de
```

What shoud I do to give maximum permissions to my user?

I'm using Windows 11 Home edition.

Comment: You could rollback to Windows 10 (you have 10 days). [link](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000196921/how-to-roll-back-a-windows-11-update-if-there-are-issues).

Comment: Isn't that a GPO related error message? As to the BT drivers, you can likely find updated ones through the BT OEM's website _(not the PC OEM's, but the OEM of the BT card itself - likely Intel or Broadcom)_. That being said, there is some hardware from the Windows ≤8 era that will never get updated drivers and will simply never function correctly on Windows ≥11 _(for example, I have a Realtek card reader on my Alienware 18 that will never work correctly on Win11 since compatible drivers simply don't exist for it)_

Comment: 1, CMD is `wmic useraccount get name,sid` 2. Is, or was, this a corporate PC? If so, you'll need to have Group Policy edited. See https://www.serverbrain.org/network-security-2003/analyzing-group-policy-using-the-registry.html

Comment: What’s “SO” in this context?

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound SO is OS (Operating System) in Portuguese. I've corrected the question